# Chrome different versions different outputs

Tags: google-chrome, multiple-versions

Im styling a Joomla site (I will never in my life work with Joomla again not for all the tea in China) and I was specifically aware of the outputs in IE, but now I realize that there are huge differences between different chrome versions outputs, even with the shame OS (mac).
Is there anyway I can check how the bloody site looks like with different chrome versions?
The pages that do screenshots wont do the job, as much of this disorders appear in loged areas...

Please help me, I need to finish this and forget Joomla for the rest of my life.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, it was not a problem of the Chrome version but the screen resolution.
I'm a bit obfuscated after this fight with Joomla.